# Memory order and visibility in Java thread

Tags: java, java-memory-model

```
class S {
    public int x = 100; 
}

class T {
    public void do(S s){
       new Thread( () -> { 
            System.out.println(s.x);
        };).start();
    }
}


class M {
    public static void main(String[] args){
       T t = new T();
       S s = new S();
       s.x = 101;
       t.do(s);
    }
}
```

Hello,

Is `T::do` guaranteed to see always s.x == 101? Why it is or why it is not?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: what are you thinking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start a thread, this introduces a memory barrier where anything which happened before you started the thread will be visible. Note: starting a thread takes a very long time in computer terms.

BTW System.out.println is a synchronized method which add full read/write memory barriers although in this case, that won't matter/

Comment: thanks for your response :)
"System.out.println is a synchronized method which add full read/write memory barriers". It changes nothing because we have no barrier on writing to `s.x`. Yes? However, as you said, this piece of code is ok because there is another guarantee of HB

Comment: @user10121051 while you need a write and read memory barrier for guaranteed behaviour. Adding just one can change the behaviour and make it harder to spot memory consistency issues through testing.

Comment: yes. And this is why full memory barrier introuduced by `SOUT` is meaningless. Yes?

Comment: @user10121051 in this case, yes, but it is common in this sort of question that it does matter.